# Really strange behaviour in android firebaseRecycleAdapter checkbox

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to following problem:

I have a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with checkboxes. It looks like this:

[image]

Everything works fine until you click two checkboxes in a row. In this case: if I where to click on listItem 3 this happends:

[image]

It duplicates the behaviour in the previous checked listitem

The code that is responsible for this is:

```
            listCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Log.i("boxPosition", String.valueOf(position));
                                if (listCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                                    Log.i("boxChecked", String.valueOf(position));
                                    mDoneListRef.child(list_id).child("ticked").setValue(Boolean.valueOf(true));
                                } else if (!listCheckbox.isChecked()){
                                        Log.i("boxChecked", String.valueOf(position));
                                        mDoneListRef.child(list_id).child("ticked").setValue(Boolean.valueOf(false));
                                }

                            }
                        });
```

I found it only happens when the else if statement is added. If I only work with the logic of the if statement everything works like expected (execpt that you cant set the value false because the missing else if / else statement).

I assume there is something wrong with the else if statement. So again, the problem only happends when the else if statement is added and you tick two checkboxes to the same value in a row.

Am I perhaps missing something to break to loop or something that resets the value of the position?

**edit** : I tried different onclickevents, creating and calling another databaseRefference in the clickevent. Neither of these called things seem to work. They all give the same result

Comment: onCheckedChanged is not good practice for such behavior.

Comment: What do you recommend ?

Comment: Well it fits to your design, Show a progress when use check/uncheck on CheckBox and make CheckBox GONE untill you get the Callback from firebase . After callback Make Check box Visible and Progress gone . As Firebase calls are network calls it will take latency So its better way to manage it in adapter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researching I found out that after the box is ticked, it should call         `notifyItemChanged(position);` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged();`